# Can anyone explain me how the voltage divider network works?

Tags: voltage-divider, voltage-reference

Can anyone explain me why the voltage of the red circle is 1.85V?

[image]

I know how the 25k-25k divider works but just don't know how the +5V-200k network affects the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use superposition principle.

First set 3.3V to 0V and solve for \$V_O'\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj6ayC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$V_O' = 5V*\frac{25k||25k}{25k||25k + 200k} = 5V*\frac{12.5k}{12.5k + 200k} = 0.2941V  $$
Next turn on 3.3V and turn off 5V source (set to 0V)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUyaUa.png)</sup>

$$V_O''= 3.3V * \frac{25k||200k}{25k+25k||200k} =  3.3V\frac{22.22k}{22.22k + 25k} = 1.552V$$

and finally we have the answer $$V_O=V_O'+V_O'' = 0.294 + 1.552V = 1.846V$$

Or try to do nodal analysis.

$$\frac{3.3V - V_O}{25k\Omega} + \frac{5V - V_O}{200k\Omega}=\frac{V_O}{25k\Omega} $$  And solve for \$V_O\$

Comment: nice, showed both sensible approaches! A well-deserved upvote! (by the way, the third sensible approach would be a voltage->current source transform, which puts all components in the schematic in parallel)

Answer (score 2):

There's a really simple way to proceed when you are first learning these. I'm assuming that you already know how to compute the voltage for a voltage divider as \$V_{TH}=V\cdot\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ and that it's equivalent series resistance is also \$R_{TH}=\frac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$.

Just follow along:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzVFEC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first transition just uses what you already know how to do. It replaces \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ with their Thevenin equivalent value and computes a new Thevenin voltage, as well. That result is illustrated in the upper right corner. Then, moving towards the lower left corner, I just decided to subtract \$1.65\:\textrm{V}\$ from all the nodes to keep things simple (so long as you don't mind remembering that the subtraction took place.) It's the same thing, except that all the voltages are now off by a fixed amount. Then you just apply the same things you already know again to get the next item shown in the upper bit of the lower right area. But you need to keep in mind that we subtracted \$1.65\:\textrm{V}\$ from all the nodes, so now it's time to add that back in... which takes us to the final result.

I kept the precision in place. But you can see that it's very close to the value you show of \$1.85\:\textrm{V}\$. As it should be.

---

There are lots of other approaches to these kinds of problems that you'll learn about and, probably also, you will learn some "rules of thumb," too.

For example, let's look at the upper right equivalent schematic again. I subtracted a voltage to go from there to the next step, so that you could use a simple voltage divider method again. However, it is possible to avoid that step and go directly to the answer if you memorize this rule (rather than the one I mentioned at the top of this answer.)

$$\begin{align*}
V_{TH}&=\frac{V_1\cdot R_2 + V_2\cdot R_1}{R_1+R_2}\\\\
&=\frac{1.65\:\textrm{V}\cdot 200\:\textrm{k}\Omega + 5\:\textrm{V}\cdot 12.5\:\textrm{k}\Omega}{200\:\textrm{k}\Omega+12.5\:\textrm{k}\Omega}\\\\
&\approx 1.84706\:\textrm{V}
\end{align*}$$

This allows you do compute the Thevenin equivalent voltage without relying upon the fact that one of the resistors is always grounded.

---

Another method you'll learn later, I hope, will be about treating all the branches individually. There are three of them here. What you do is to just mentally set \$V_X=0\:\textrm{V}\$ for a moment and compute all the currents flowing into \$V_x\$ as a result of doing that. (There will be no currents flowing in from \$R_2\$ since it is grounded already.) Then take all the connected resistances and just treat them as being in parallel and compute that resistance. Multiply the two values you get (the total current and the total resistance) to get the voltage:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{TH}&=\left[\frac{3.3\:\textrm{V}}{25\:\textrm{k}\Omega}+\frac{5\:\textrm{V}}{200\:\textrm{k}\Omega}\right]\cdot\bigg[25\:\textrm{k}\Omega\vert\vert 25\:\textrm{k}\Omega\vert\vert 200\:\textrm{k}\Omega \bigg]\\\\
&=\left[132\:\mu\textrm{A}+25\:\mu\textrm{A}\right]\cdot\left[12.5\:\textrm{k}\Omega\vert\vert 200\:\textrm{k}\Omega \right]\\\\
&\approx 157\:\mu\textrm{A}\cdot 11.7647\:\textrm{k}\Omega\\\\
&\approx 1.84706\:\textrm{V}
\end{align*}$$

This may sound like a trick. But there is a way you can think about it that may work. I'm first setting \$V_X=0\:\textrm{V}\$ to see how much current flows *into* the node (or wire), if I do that. But I know that all the current flowing into the node *must* also flow back out of it, as well. So then I just ask, "what is the effective resistance that opposes that outward flow back out of the node?" That's where I just compute the effective outward *resistance*. Knowing the current flowing in and knowing the resistance opposing it's flow back out, I can compute the voltage required by simply computing \$V=I_{total}\cdot R_{total}\$ in the usual way. That's a way to look at why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to view this circuit is as a circuit for creating weighted averages with the weight being the conductance of each resistor. This follows from the superposition arguments or node voltage arguments but it's very useful to know when you are trying to go the other way and design circuits like this to fill some useful role

So we have 0V with a weight of 1/25 3.3V with a weight of 1/25 and 5V with a weight of 1/200

Total weight is 0.085

Output voltage is ((0 * 1/25) + (3.3*1/25) + (5 * 1/200))/0.085 = (0.132 + 0.025)/0.085 ~= 1.847

Answer (score -1):

Please see circuit below for reference.

Lets call the current through R1, I1; R2, I2 and finally R3, I3. The node in the middle will be V.

So, from this we can write that I3 = I1 + I2.

You should be able to find I1 and I2 easily, substitute, do some algebra and you will hopefully have the correct answer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f02f2Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>